# How do you get the enclosing instance of an instance? (com.sun.jdi)

Tags: java, inner-classes, jdi

`com.sun.jdi` is a package that lets you get information about a running VM, add breakpoints, look through stack frames, etc.

How can I get the enclosing instance of another instance? For example, here is some code that creates 4 instances of the inner class Garfield.Lasagna, with two each being enclosed by a different instance of Garfield.

```
public class Garfield {
 int belly;
 public class Lasagna {
    Lasagna() {belly++;}
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Garfield g1 = new Garfield();
    Lasagna l11 = g1.new Lasagna();
    Lasagna l12 = g1.new Lasagna();
    Garfield g2 = new Garfield();
    Lasagna l21 = g2.new Lasagna();
    Lasagna l22 = g2.new Lasagna();
 }
}
```

I would imagine that [com.sun.jdi.ObjectReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/ObjectReference.html) would have a way to get at the instance enclosing an instance, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Or, I would try to use reflection in the debugged VM, something like [java.lang.Class.getEnclosing{Class,Constructor,Method}()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) but I don't see any related method that applies to objects/instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can both access it through the JDI and through reflection. The enclosing instance is stored as a field of instances of the inner class `Lasanga`. The automatically-generated name for the field is usually `this$0` (so in the example above, the field with this name has type `Garfield`).

To access it in the JDI, you have to use the ReferenceType of the ObjectReference. There are [three relevant methods of ReferenceType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/ReferenceType.html):

- fields() gives you all simple fields and also these synthetic fields
- visibleFields() additionally gives you inherited fields
- allFields() additionally gives you hidden fields (and possibly repeats synthetic fields)

Accessing it through reflection is the same as usual, just ask for the field of name `"this$0"`.

But, you can't access the synthetically-defined variable at compile time, asking for the field `this$0` will cause a compile-time error.